# Which countries have still NOT yet reported a case of COVID-19 Coronavirus?

Tags: international-travel, safety, health, covid-19

I keep finding sites that list or map countries WITH Coronavirus.  I'd like the inverse - a list of countries that have yet to report a case of Covid-19.

Comment: +1 for the question because I want to know the answer but this is a moving target! Plus, are we going to rollback some countries when the last person in a country is cured or dead?

Comment: @Itai no, as the countries have reported one.  I think when we get to the stage that countries are cleared (Nepal managed it, for now), we might have a different question.

Comment: You stating you want a list of countries (without reported cases) to travel to. Do not do this. You might not be able to come back to your country due to future flight restrictions. The other thing is: there is a non neglectible chance that some of these countries health system isnso disfuntional that the reason for zero reported cases is that they either dont know they have cases or dont want to know.

Comment: Yeah I'm in New Zealand, we're not going anywhere any time soon.  Borders are closed.

Comment: Comments unlocked for now but please only post comments on whether this question does fit on the site or why is does not. All other comments will be wiped as they should have been posted in the chatroom.

Comment: A meta post about this question, for further discussion: [I think a question is off-topic but it's been under bounty for three weeks. What can I do?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6534/i-think-a-question-is-off-topic-but-its-been-under-bounty-for-three-weeks-what)

Comment: I think this question is off-topic.  No traveller has any practical use of a list of countries that aren't affected by COVID-19.  It doesn't matter, because one shouldn't and possibly can't travel there now anyway.

Comment: The situation with bounties on this question has also spurred a discussion on Mother Meta: [Is repeatedly clearing and reinstating a bounty as a moderator considered abuse?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345849).

Comment: This question may not have practical travel purposes at this time, that was not a given when it was asked. Besides, it is a topic that many of our members are interested in. If having normal user voting, I would vote to keep open (and if needed to re-open.)

Comment: @Willeke even then, it's ephemeral. Would an equivalent question asking for places that didn't experience the 1918 Spanish Flu be considered a useful travel question today? Maybe that would be a good History question, but it's not useful for travelers today.

Answer (score 13):

Please move countries to the second list below as they confirm infections, with a link to an official source.  The [ArcGIS dashboard](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6) is good enough to be considered official.

**Countries / territories with zero reported infections**

1. Turkmenistan
2. Tuvalu

**Countries with reported infections**

- Afghanistan ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Albania ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Algeria ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Andorra ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Angola ([evidence](https://informante.web.na/angola-registered-its-first-coronavirus-case/))
- Antigua and Barbuda ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Argentina ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Armenia ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Azerbaijan ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Australia ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Austria ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Bahamas ([evidence](http://www.loopnewsbarbados.com/content/bahamas-first-confirmed-coronavirus-patient-has-no-travel-history))
- Bahrain ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Barbados ([evidence](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries))
- Belarus ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Belgium ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Belize ([evidence](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries))
- Benin ([evidence](http://ortb.bj/urgent-coronavirus-le-benin-confirme-un-premier-cas/))
- Bangladesh ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Bhutan ([evidence](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries))
- Bolivia ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Bosnia and Herzegovina ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Botswana ([evidence](https://news.trust.org/item/20200330172800-r44d6/))
- Brazil ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Brunei ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Bulgaria ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Burkina Faso ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Burundi ([evidence](https://www.reuters.com/article/health-coronavirus-burundi/east-african-nation-of-burundi-confirms-first-coronavirus-cases-health-ministry-idUSL8N2BO34B))
- Cabo Verde ([evidence](https://www.publico.pt/2020/03/20/mundo/noticia/coronavirus-ingles-62-anos-caso-confirmado-cabo-verde-1908619))
- Cambodia ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Cameroon ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Canada ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Central African Republic (CAR) ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Chad ([evidence](https://www.alwihdainfo.com/Tchad-un-premier-cas-de-Coronavirus-detecte-Presidence_a84260.html))
- Chile ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- China ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Colombia ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Comoros (([evidence](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries))
- Congo, Democratic Republic of the ([evidence](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-health-coronavirus-congo/congo-health-authorities-stumble-with-first-coronavirus-case-confusion-idUSKBN2110K0))
- Costa Rica ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Cote d'Ivoire ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Croatia ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Cuba ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Cyprus ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Czechia ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Denmark ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Djibouti ([evidence](http://french.xinhuanet.com/afrique/2020-03/18/c_138891198.htm))
- Dominica ([evidence](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries))
- Dominican Republic ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- East Timor ([evidence](https://www.nst.com.my/world/world/2020/03/576783/east-timor-confirms-first-case-covid-19))
- Ecuador ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Egypt   ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- El Salvador ([evidence](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries))
- Equatorial Guinea ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Eritrea ([evidence](http://www.branapress.com/2020/03/21/breaking-eritrea-confirms-first-coronavirus-case/))
- Estonia ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Eswatini (formerly Swaziland) ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Ethiopia ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Fiji ([evidence](https://www.stuff.co.nz/national/health/coronavirus/120413536/fiji-has-first-confirmed-first-case-of-coronavirus))
- Finland ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- France ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Gabon ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Gambia ([evidence](https://nationalpost.com/pmn/health-pmn/gambia-reports-first-case-of-coronavirus-health-minister))
- Georgia ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Germany ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Ghana ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Greece ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Grenada ([evidence](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries))
- Guatemala ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Guinea ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Guinea-Bissau ([evidence](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-health-coronavirus-bissau/guinea-bissau-confirms-first-two-cases-of-coronavirus-idUSKBN21C2EA))
- Guyana ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Haiti ([evidence](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries))
- Honduras ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Hungary ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Iceland ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- India ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Indonesia ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Iran ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Iraq ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Ireland ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Israel ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Italy ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Jamaica ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Japan ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Jordan ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Kazakhstan ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Kenya ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Kiribati ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Kosovo ([evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_coronavirus_pandemic_in_Kosovo))
- Kuwait ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Kyrgyzstan ([evidence](https://fergana.news/news/116173/))
- Laos ([evidence](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries))
- Latvia ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Lebanon ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Lesotho (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_pandemic_by_country_and_territory#Countries_and_dependent_territories_without_confirmed_cases)
- Liberia ([evidence](https://www.aa.com.tr/en/africa/liberia-announces-1st-coronavirus-case/1768162))
- Libya ([evidence](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries))
- Liechtenstein ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Lithuania ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Luxembourg ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Madagascar ([evidence](https://www.usnews.com/news/world/articles/2020-03-20/madagascar-confirms-first-cases-of-coronavirus-president))
- Malaysia ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Malawi ([evidence](https://twitter.com/bnltimes/status/1245749721794256899))
- Mali ([evidence](https://www.usnews.com/news/world/articles/2020-03-25/mali-reports-first-two-cases-of-coronavirus-government-statement))
- Maldives ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Malta ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Mauritania ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Mauritius ([evidence](https://twitter.com/BTSMauritius/status/1240349833342464003))
- Marshall Islands ([evidence](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/oct/29/remote-marshall-islands-records-its-first-coronavirus-cases))
- Mexico ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Micronesia ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Moldova ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Monaco ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Mongolia ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Montenegro ([evidence](https://www.total-montenegro-news.com/news/5458-coronavirus-in-montenegro))
- Morocco ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Mozambique ([evidence](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries))
- Myanmar (formerly Burma) ([evidence](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries))
- Namibia ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Nauru ([evidence](https://covid19.who.int/region/wpro/country/nr/))
- Nepal  ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Netherlands, the  ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- New Zealand ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Nicaragua ([evidence](https://www.articulo66.com/2020/03/18/rosario-murillo-confirma-primer-caso-de-coronavirus-en-nicaragua/))
- Niger ([evidence](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries))
- Nigeria ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- North Korea ([evidence](https://www.stuff.co.nz/world/asia/300586867/north-korea-raises-alarm-after-confirming-first-ever-covid19-case-since-pandemic-began))
- North Macedonia (formerly Macedonia) ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Norway ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Oman ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Pakistan ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Palau ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Palestine ([evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_coronavirus_pandemic_in_the_State_of_Palestine))
- Panama ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Paraguay ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Papua New Guinea ([evidence](https://m.facebook.com/watch/?v=221945402521984&_rdr))
- Peru ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Philippines ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Poland ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Portugal ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Qatar ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Romania ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Russia ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Rwanda ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Saint Kitts and Nevis  ([evidence](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries))
- Saint Lucia ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Saint Vincent and the Grenadines ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Samoa [evidence](https://www.nzherald.co.nz/nz/covid-19-coronavirus-samoas-first-case-a-sailor-who-arrived-on-repatriation-flight-from-auckland/EYMGY2QGDUGXSXQCV3XBEP4LRM/)
- Sao Tome and Principe ([evidence](https://africa.cgtn.com/2020/04/06/sao-tome-and-principe-confirms-its-first-four-covid-19-cases/))
- San Marino ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Saudi Arabia ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Senegal ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Serbia ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Seychelles ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Sierra Leone ([evidence](https://www.usnews.com/news/world/articles/2020-03-31/sierra-leone-has-confirmed-its-first-case-of-coronavirus-president-says))
- Singapore ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Slovakia ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Slovenia ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Solomon Islands ([evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_pandemic_in_the_Solomon_Islands))
- Somalia ([evidence](https://regionweek.com/somalia-becomes-the-30th-african-country-with-confirmed-covid-19-cases/))
- South Africa ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- South Korea ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- South Sudan ([evidence](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://time.com/5815838/south-sudan-africa-coronavirus-covid-19/&ved=2ahUKEwjb6fGYktLoAhU8FTQIHY7fCYEQqOcBMAF6BAgKEAM&usg=AOvVaw1lp9vcZs_oD4KD9sHtB4iO))
- Spain ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Sri Lanka ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Sudan ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Suriname ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Sweden ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Switzerland ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Syria ([evidence](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries))
- Taiwan  ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Tajikistan ([evidence](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries))
- Tanzania ([evidence](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries))
- Thailand ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Togo ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Tonga ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Trinidad and Tobago ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Tunisia ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Turkey ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Uganda ([evidence](https://twitter.com/MinofHealthUG/status/1241469504087035904))
- Ukraine ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- United Arab Emirates (UAE) ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- United Kingdom (UK) ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- United States of America (USA) ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Uruguay ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Uzbekistan ([evidence](https://fergana.ru/news/116055/))
- Vanuatu ([evidence](https://www.nzherald.co.nz/world/coronavirus-vanuatu-records-first-case-of-covid-19/PFXDDXGIOX5FVW6E63JZHMY23U/))
- Vatican City (Holy See) ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Venezuela ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Vietnam ([evidence](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6))
- Yemen ([evidence](https://www.jpost.com/Breaking-News/Coronavirus-Yemen-confirms-first-case-624225))
- Zambia ([evidence](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries))
- Zimbabwe ([evidence](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries))

Comment: @AndrewGrimm we had an original list. Definitely some are missing but are probably included in the lower list (eg Greenland). Besides, it has cases.  If we're missing countries/territories in the top list, I think that's more important for this question.

Comment: Samoa has a suspected case

Comment: I think North Korea had a suspected case too, but he was reportedly executed for breaking quarantine.

Comment: This answers the question of where, but to fully answer the question "of countries to travel to," list 1 needs an indication if the countries are restricting visitors.  If they really have no cases, then they would be wise to do so.

Comment: Burundi has not reported a case because they do not have the capacity to test for Covid-19. They are probably not the only ones...

Comment: @zeocrash An extreme, yet effective way of keeping your nation's COVID-19 death toll at 0.

Comment: @KristvanBesien seems that changed: https://www.aa.com.tr/en/africa/burundi-confirms-first-2-covid-19-cases/1787083

Comment: @MarkMayo: Was bound to happen. Several countries have been sending medical supplies (which I suppose would include test kits) to poorer countries to help them.

Answer (score 5):

Wikipedia maintains a list of countries and territories with no confirmed cases of COVID-19:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_pandemic_by_country_and_territory#Countries_and_territories_with_no_confirmed_cases ([mirror on  2020-03-28](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=2019%E2%80%9320_coronavirus_pandemic_by_country_and_territory&oldid=947749378#Entities_without_confirmed_cases))

It lists both UN member states and external territories.